# Redirect serial com to tcp port

Tags: tcp, serial-port, com

I would like to know if exists some utility that connects to serial port and redirect input and output to a tcp port.
I need this for a Java application, I need to write and read to a serial port but seems very hard... java will better work with socket connection.

MIND: I found a lot of "virtual com to tcp" but I have a real com! And I want to connect to its.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's pretty easy. Under Linux there are serial devices, redirection and netcat for that. On the server you can run a netcat process listening on a given tcp port with stdin and stdout redirected to/from the serial device like that:

```
nc -l 9801 > /dev/ttyS0 < /dev/ttyS0
```

Where 9801 in this example is the tcp port to listen on.  You can setup the serial port with `setserial(8)`.

These [device files also exist on cygwin (Windows)](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-posixdevices).

Comment: Is there a solution also for windows? Usign java I would like to run my app as multiplatform.

Comment: Windows: Use Hub4Com, see my [gist](https://gist.github.com/arberg/0378204852551950f4ecb809102df2fb)

Linux: With added redirect of input and output to log-files: 

    `cat /dev/ttyUSB0 | tee /var/log/lyngdorfSerial.ComToTcp.log | netcat -l 7000  | tee /var/log/lyngdorfSerial.TcpToCom.log > /dev/ttyUSB0 &`


[see full script](https://gist.github.com/arberg/ca4b325632034b218c2de4a353132b4f)

Answer (score 9):

I think [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) has [the functionality you are looking for](http://www.rfc1149.net/blog/2011/12/01/accessing-serial-ports-the-easy-way/) as well.

```
$ socat TCP-LISTEN:4161,fork,reuseaddr FILE:/dev/ttyUSB0,b57600,raw
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that you can redirect your serial port with the software, like this , for example https://www.eltima.com/serial-port-redirector/

But, still it will redirect the data from the serial port to another machine without serial connection, thus creating a virtual serial com.

Comment: your answer is like a comment